# Как изменить id элемента с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Не получается изменить id элемента.

Код:

```
var div = document.querySelector(".div");
            if(pass != repass){
                div.id = "false";
```

Что не так? Искал ответ, как правильно его изменить, у меня должно быть все правильно.

Comment: "у меня должно быть все правильно" - Бизнес-идея - продавать наклейки/плакаты с этим девизом. Будет дико популярно у программистов.

Comment: Неправильно, в первую очередь, то, что Вы поместили в вопрос огрызок кода, вырвав его из контекста страницы/события, в которых он выполняется, и не объяснив, какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить.

Comment: а класс точно называется div ? или мы ищем тэг ?

Comment: `div.id = "false";` вполне рабочий код. Ошибка в другом месте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно.
И, в данном случае можно обойтись без `if` (типкаст в строку выполняется автоматически).

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.test'), 
    updateContent = () => { el.textContent = ''; el.textContent = el.outerHTML; }; 
updateContent(); 

function changeId(newId) {
  el.id = newId; 
  updateContent(); 
}
```

```css
body { font: 18px sans-serif; }

.test {
  min-width: 500px; height: 2em; 
  padding: 0 1ch; 
  background-color: #333; 
  font: 18px monospace; color: #1d1; 
  line-height: 2.3em; 
}

label, label input {
  display: inline-block; 
  font: 1.2em sans-serif; 
}
label { margin: 10px 0 0 20px; }
input {
  max-width: 10ch; 
  vertical-align: -0.05em;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="changeId(this.checked)">Булевое значение</label><br>
<label>Строковое значение <input type="text" maxlength="16" oninput="changeId(this.value)"></label>
```

Либо неправильно выбираете целевой элемент (это самое вероятное), либо значение `pass` при выполнении равно `repass` ...